# Getting error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'numpy.dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I import this csv file:

```
sales = pd.read_csv('http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv')
```

I am trying to make pivot table but I notice when I do this:

```
sales.pivot_table(index='Product', columns='Payment_Type', values= 'Price' )
```

I get an error

> Price column is string dtype

Then I try to convert the column to float and do this:

```
sales.Price.astype('float64')
```

Then, it shows

> Error: could not convert string to float: '13,000'

I realize there's a value in `Price` column with comma in it, so float conversion can't happen. So I remove the comma by method below and use `iloc` to check if it worked and it did, that value changed to 13000:

```
sales['Price']= sales.Price.str.replace(',', '')

sales.iloc[558, 2]
```

And when I try to convert the Price column to float64 I again get this error which I don't understand:

```
sales['Price'] = sales.Price.astype('int64')
```

> Error: Getting error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'numpy.dtype'

Does anyone know what is happening? What type is this `numpy.dtype`? It's neither `numpy.float64` nor `numpy.int64`.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your correct command

```
sales['Price'] = sales.Price.astype('int64')
```

you highly likely performed the command

```
sales['Price'] = sales.Price.dtype
```

which changed strings in the `Price` column to dtypes.

Repeat all your commands (without `sales['Price'] = sales.Price.dtype`) and it will be OK.